# How can I plot a pandas multiindex dataframe as 3d

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d, bar3d

I have a dataframe `df` grouped like this:

```
Year    Product Sales
2010        A   111
            B   20
            C   150
2011        A   10
            B   28
            C   190
            …   …
```

and I would like to plot this in `matplotlib` as 3d Chart having the `Year` as the x-axis, `Sales` on the y-axis and `Product` on the z-axis.
[image]

I have been trying the following:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X = dfgrouped['Year']
Y = dfgrouped['Sales']
Z = dfgrouped['Product']
ax.bar(X, Y, Z, color=cs, alpha=0.8)
```

unfortunately I am getting

> "ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 7 or
>   scalar"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could plot a 3D Bar graph using `Pandas` as shown:

**Setup:**

```
arrays = [[2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011],['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Year', 'Product'])         

df = pd.DataFrame({'Sales': [111, 20, 150, 10, 28, 190]}, index=index)
print (df)

              Sales
Year Product       
2010 A          111
     B           20
     C          150
2011 A           10
     B           28
     C          190
```

**Data Wrangling:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set plotting style
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
```

Grouping similar entries (*get_group*) occuring in the Sales column and iterating through them and later appending them to a `list`. This gets stacked horizontally using [`np.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) which forms the `z` dimension of the 3d plot.

```
L = []
for i, group in df.groupby(level=1)['Sales']:
    L.append(group.values)
z = np.hstack(L).ravel()
```

Letting the labels on both the x and y dimensions take unique values of the respective levels of the Multi-Index Dataframe. The x and y dimensions then take the range of these values.

```
xlabels = df.index.get_level_values('Year').unique()
ylabels = df.index.get_level_values('Product').unique()
x = np.arange(xlabels.shape[0])
y = np.arange(ylabels.shape[0])
```

Returning coordinate matrices from coordinate vectors using [`np.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)

```
x_M, y_M = np.meshgrid(x, y, copy=False)
```

**3-D plotting:**

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Making the intervals in the axes match with their respective entries
ax.w_xaxis.set_ticks(x + 0.5/2.)
ax.w_yaxis.set_ticks(y + 0.5/2.)

# Renaming the ticks as they were before
ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(xlabels)
ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(ylabels)

# Labeling the 3 dimensions
ax.set_xlabel('Year')
ax.set_ylabel('Product')
ax.set_zlabel('Sales')

# Choosing the range of values to be extended in the set colormap
values = np.linspace(0.2, 1., x_M.ravel().shape[0])

# Selecting an appropriate colormap
colors = plt.cm.Spectral(values)
ax.bar3d(x_M.ravel(), y_M.ravel(), z*0, dx=0.5, dy=0.5, dz=z, color=colors)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

**Note:**

Incase of unbalanced `groupby` objects, you could still do it by `unstacking`
and filling `Nans` with 0's and then `stacking` it back as follows:

```
df = df_multi_index.unstack().fillna(0).stack()
```

where `df_multi_index.unstack` is your original multi-index dataframe.

For the new values added to the Multi-index Dataframe, following plot is obtained:

[image: Image2]

Comment: Thanks Nickil Maveli, this seems to bring me a bit closer to the solution. I have edited the question to Show a bit better what I would like to achieve. in your answer somehow the bars are flat and they are not shown on the Position for each Product?  Do I always have to do reset_index to do the plot?

Comment: I hope my *edited response* indeed is what you wanted it to look like. I've kept the `Multi-Index` dataframe object untouched and so you could plot it without converting it into a `dataframe` object using `reset_index`.

Comment: awesome it works! Thank you. I think I will still have to digest the code a bit, though :-)   The only Thing is that it doenst work anymore if I add another value to the dataframe e.g.  '2012'  'A'  '105' then I am getting the error 'ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (42,1) (54,4) '    Do you know where I have to change the code for that?

Comment: Yes. Those were the shortcomings of my earlier method. I've rectified it and shown the plot for the new values mentioned by you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats a great solution!